# Why using parent alias from a template derived class can't be deduced automatically?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17, type-alias

In C++17, consider a base template class that has an alias to get the vectorized type of the enclosed type:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    using VectorType = vector<T>;
};
```

In a non-template derived class, we can simply use `VectorType` as:

```cpp
struct Bar : public Foo<int> {
    VectorType Get(VectorType t) { return t; }
};
```

Now if we want to use it in a template derived class, we need to use `using typename`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct BarT : public Foo<T> {
    using typename Foo<T>::VectorType;

    VectorType Get(VectorType t) { return t; }
};
```

From what I initially thought, it should be possible to be deduced automatically by the compiler, no?

Is there any better way such that I don't have to retype it for multiple aliases in the derived classes?

Comment: You should be able to omit `typename` in this context in C++20.